# Total Comment count for every post in admin panel

Tags: mysql

I am working a CMS where inside admin panel I wanted to display total comments count for every post,

I have two different tables:
posts and comments, in which comments are linked with posts with a column 'comment_post_id'

Can anyone help to write SQL QUERY by which I can echo total count of comments for every post?

Comment: Please provide [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    p.*,
    COUNT(1) as nr_comments
FROM posts p
JOIN comments c ON c.comment_post_id = p.post_id
GROUP BY p.post_id
```